# Strange thing happening with image thumbnails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a strange problem when I am trying to share a link from my site. The image does not appear, but when I go to the debugger tool it appears normally, and it appears in Facebook too, but I cant do that with all of my links. Here is an example; the link `http://vid.sanka7a.com/musicvideo.php?vid=831408952` is not appearing in Facebook.

And if we put it in the debugger tool, it will appear.

So what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Facebook's taking the value of your `<link rel="image_src" href="831408952-1.jpg">` meta tag as an alternate option for the image.

Because of that Facebook's trying to fetch `http://vid.sanka7a.com/831408952-1.jpg` (which is an HTTP 404) in the composer instead of the supplied `og:image` value.

I didn't realise that this can happen but updating the `image_src` tag to point to the same URL as the `og:url` tag should resolve the issue.